# Javascript variable initialization

Tags: php, javascript

There, an odd thing just happened..

Normally I assign my global variables like this:

```
orders = [];
pOrders = [];
```

But I was lazy and just wrote:

```
orders = pOrders = [];
```

It should mean the same, shouldn't it??

Apparently not because the array `pOrder` also contained the array `orders` data. I sat for 15 min looking for a bug in my code but couldn't find any so I just tried writing the variables as I normally would and it worked. Why does this happen?

In PHP, the logic would be the same, but JavaScript seems to behave differently.

Please could anyone provide me with some information, or knowledge..

Comment: Note that Java and JavaScript are completely different languages.

Comment: Thanks, I realised this once it happened, my question would be, why in PHP is it different? PHP would assign each array as a blank array and not reference the first with the second...

Comment: @Jacques Design decision by the makers of PHP. They wanted their variable initialization to work like that.

Answer (score 7):

In the second example, you're explicitly assigning the exact same array instance to two separate variables. There's only one array involved, while in the first case there are two.

I would be somewhat surprised to learn that PHP really would treat those two pieces of code as meaning the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I realised this once it happened, my question would be, why in PHP is it different? PHP would assign each array as a blank array and not reference the first with the second...

Answer (score 5):

That code you wrote there last is the same as:

```
orders = [];
pOrders = orders;
```

So now you have two variables which are references to the same array. That's why you are exeriencing this behavior.

When instead you do it as you did in your first example:

```
orders = [];
pOrders = [];
```

Then you have two completely separate and distinct arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You assigned both variables to refer to the **same** array instance.

Answer (score 1):

To see what everyone means by "same array instance", run the following JavaScript in your browser:

```
orders = pOrders = [];
orders.push("hello");
pOrders.push("world");
console.log(orders);
console.log(pOrders);
```

Check the console output, both messages will say ["hello", "world"].